# How to use "this" keyword inside array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, this

Here I have an array which consists of n number of objects which are similar to this.

```
var views = [
  {
    id: "chart-0",
    datasource: "",
    type: "batch",
    context: "/analytics/device/stats/",
    schema: [
      {
        "metadata": {
          "names": [""],
          "types": [""]
        }
      }
    ],
    columns: [
      {
        "name": "month",
        "label": "month",
        "type": "linear",
      }, 
      {
        "name": "minValue",
        "label": "minValue",
        "type": "linear"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "maxValue",
        "label": "maxValue",
        "type": "linear",
        "axis": "y"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "time",
        "label": "time",
        "type": "time",
        "axis": "x"
      },
    ],
    callbacks: [
      {
        type: "click",
        callback: function() {}
      }
    ],
    data: function() {
      var COLUMNS = views[0].columns;
    }
  }
];
```

I want to access some of the fields inside **data** function. I can access id, datasource simply **this.id** or **this.datasource**. How to access **columns** inside data function using **this** keyword instead of **views[0].columns**

Comment: There is no `columns` property in the view

Comment: er, `data` is a function. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: How is the `data` function called?

Comment: @Arun updated question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yckpufmk/1/?

Comment: @Andy added columns fields

Comment: @GPrathap it will depend on how `data` is invoked, so you need to share us how the function is called... if you are calling `view.data()` then `this.columns` should work

Comment: Well it will be `views[n].data()` depending on the array length but [it should still work](https://jsfiddle.net/531k0sze/).

Comment: @Andy yes, you are correct. it should be this.columns as you mentioned. thanks

Comment: Why not just do `this.columns`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know that you can use the this key word to assign id, distance, or any other property would be to pass the data into a function.

```
// create a function and pass in a reference to the views array and specify the objects index you want to operate on.

function chanceProperty( views[0]) {
    var currentColumns = this.columns;  // gives you a reference to the objects columns array. "This" is a reference to the object that was passed in.

// you can then do your operations on the properties in that array either with a loop or by specifically targeting an object.

    currentColumns[1].name = "myNewMinValue";

// or

    currentColumns.forEach( function(val, idx) {
        currentColumns[idx].name = "allTheSame";
    });

}
```

**update**

I thin I see what you are trying to do. You want pass some of your views properties to your data function. You don't need "this" for that. You can just pass the properties you want to the data function.

```
data: function(id, dataSource, columns) {
    var COLUMNS = views[0].columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
data: function() {
  var COLUMNS = this.columns;

  return COLUMNS;
}
```

And you will be able to access columns inside data function:

```
views[0].data();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` needs care. Well you can access `views[0].columns` by saying `this.columns` but under two conditions.

1. You must call the function like `views[0].data();` and only then the `this` in the `data` function will refer to the `views` object. In other words if you might like to pass `views[0].data` as a callback, you better be careful because if you do  like `doStg(arg1, arg2, views[0].data)` then `this` will no longer refer to the `views[0]` object but to the global or window scope. So you must pass callbacks like `doStg(arg1, arg2, function(){views[0].data})`
2. Somehow instead of conventional method if you would like to define `views[0].data` as an arrow function, then forget about using `this`. Since then `this` would only refer to the limited scope it resides in which is the function's own scope (not even `views[0]` object)